# Firing an event on a particular page in Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

In Google Tag Manager I'd like to fire an event when a particular page is seen. This is for a completed signup page - a conversion.

In Google Tag Manager I have my base UA tag fire on all pages.

I then created a new UA tag "Subscriptions" to track events: track type events. I then filled in my category, action and label values for the event.

However, it's the rules that seem to be tricky.

When I went through the signup process in order to see the conversion page, here is all the info from Google Analytics debug in the JavaScript console:

```
Account ID               : UA-xxxxxx-2
Page Title               : Example Company | Your Account has been created | Premium
Host Name                : secure.example.com


Page                     : /secure/common/callback?`

https://secure.example.com/secure/common/callback?id=2c92a0fb41ee0b8c0142062c06fd6c89&tenantId=3415&timestamp=1390480077277&token=WByfk6aU4JX1EJSchx4XDMnp50XX8aL7&responseSignature=OTg2OWY4MTcwMDVmZmRiYzI3NWI2N2IxOWJmNTYxNGI=&success=true&refId=2c92a0fb43bdc33a0143bf122e6d3ebb&field_passthrough1=:Unmyname@gmail.com:Emmyname@gmail.com&field_passthrough2=P&field_passthrough5=%3Alnen%3ANmmeFirstNAme%20meLastName%3AA1123%20mainst%20Avenue%3AA2%3ACtPhiladelphia%3AStON%3APcM6G%202T8%3ACn&field_passthrough3=3a5e49b5-85ed-4c86-99af-761004f7db06&field_passthrough4=true&signature=OWM1NjY5MGZkMWVjNjI5NjJiYjk3MmVhOWU3ZjkzNjA=
```

I'd like to fire the "Subscriptions" event track tag. I tried the following rule but had no success:

`{{url}}` contains: `/secure/common/callback?`.
`{{url path}}` contains: `/secure/common/callback?`.

My questions therefore are:

1. How would I fire the submissions event when this page is visited?
2. Why is the event not firing now - isn't the logic sound? If the URL
   contains `/secure/common/callback?` then it should fire, right?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not used Tag Manager but I suspect the issue is caused by the `?` at the end of you URL. My suggested solution would be to escape this so your URL will look like this:

```
/secure/common/callback\?
```

You may also want to investigate if you can use regex with your rules to make the above more accurate.